# How to pass an random variable between php pages using $_SESSION variable?

Tags: php

I am trying to use variables(dates) queried in a php page then placed in $_SESSION, in another page to perform another query.

I will only use one date from that session array. which is that one i clicked on its link tag.

Is there an action that should be performed `onclick` of that link?

Here is my php, first page it creates the $_session variables and create the links.

The second page it is supposed to print the value i clicked. but it does not.

oldentries.php:

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Tdate FROM titletable";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 )
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $_SESSION[$row["Tdate"]]= $row["Tdate"];
            echo '<a href="content.php" class="datelink">'.$_SESSION[$row["Tdate"]].'</a><br>';

        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "No Results in the database!";
    }

    ?>
```

content.php

```
<?php

 $datetable = $_SESSION[$row["Tdate"]];
 echo "$datetable";

 $query = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='council_db'";



?>
```

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` in both pages?

Comment: Is your code doing a `session_start()` anywhere? It must be done on all pages that use `$_SESSION` and it is best to do it on all pages to ensure that session does not timeout

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes on both pages, i debugged it , the $session variable is initialized with the dates. i just cant pass it to the second page. i don't know how!

Comment: @jfadich yes i do, the variable is initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$_SESSION` array is keyed by the result of the SQL query. In your `content.php` the $row variable is not available. In cases like this it's probably better to pass variables between pages with a query parameter rather than the session.

```
...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<a href="content.php?Tdate='.$row["Tdate"].'" class="datelink">'.$row["Tdate"].'</a><br>';
}
...
```

Then in `content.php` you can access it with `$_GET`

```
$datetable = $_GET["Tdate"];
```

Comment: And if you are doing something like checkboxes with multiple possible values, you can send them to php as an array by putting the square brackets on the end of the name attribute - `<input type=checkbox name=selections[] value="foo">foo <input type=checkbox name=selections[] value="bar">bar`